# AWS - how to separate resource of each user for an AWS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am opening an AWS Service (say: AWS Rekognition) for my app's users.

The problem is: when one user (ex: user1) creates a resource (such as a collection), other users (ex: user2, user3) also see the resource that was created by user1.

I have tried to use `Identity Pool`, and acquired `Token`/`Identity` from my backend server for my users but things are not better (my users still see the resources of each other).

What should I do to let user1 receive user1's resource only?

I have been struggling with this problem for days, but can't seem to figure out.

Regards

Comment: Are these "users" staff in your company, or users of your application? How are these users obtaining credentials to make calls to your AWS account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein they are the users of my applications. How they obtain the credentials: app --> my backend server ---(GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity)--> AWS Cognito, which returns to the user the `Token` and `IdentityId`. Then from app, I make a request to `Rekognition` to list/add/... collections/faces. Is my model correct? Is `AWS Cognito` the right place? Sorry I have to ask these questions since I am totally new to AWS

Comment: FYI: my app is in iOS, written in Swift, and follows this guideline: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html , `iOS - Swift` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this architecture:

**Option 1: Client/Server**

In this architecture, client apps (eg on a mobile device or a web-based app) make calls to an API that is hosted by your back-end application. The back-end app then verifies the request and **makes calls to AWS on behalf of the user**.

The user's app never receives AWS credentials. This is very secure because the back-end app can authenticate all requests and apply business logic.

**Option 2: Providing AWS credentials**

In this architecture, the client apps receive temporary AWS credentials that enables them to directly call AWS services (which matches the architecture you describe).

The benefit is that the app can directly access AWS services such as Amazon S3. The downside is that they you need to very tightly limit the permissions they are given to ensure they only access the desired resources.

Some services make this easy by allowing **Conditions** on IAM Permissions that can limit the resources that can be accessed, such as by **tag** or other identifier.

However, based upon [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon Rekognition - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonrekognition.html), there is no such capability for Amazon Rekognition:

> Rekognition has no service-specific context keys that can be used in the Condition element of policy statements.

I think you could limit the calls by providing a `Resource` string in the IAM Policy, which can limit their ability to make certain calls (eg `DeleteFaces`) so that it is only done against a specific `collection`.

However, please note that `list` calls such as `ListCollections` are either permitted fully or not at all. It is not possible to limit the list of collections returned. (This is the same as most AWS Services, such as listing EC2 instances.)

Thus, when using this method of providing credentials, you should be very careful about the permissions granted to the app.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. Summary in Option 2 (also my approach): there is no way to limit resources (such as collections) among users? i.e. a user can still see resources that were not created by her? I think I could do something in programming to limit (i.e control "who's going to see what"), but I'd like to confirm with you first whether there is no way to set it up at AWS side.

Comment: ALL resources in AWS belong to the Account in which they were created. There is no concept of users owning resources in _any_ AWS service. It is the AWS Account that owns resources. Limitations on access to create/view/modify/delete resources is granted via IAM Policies. By default, users have no permissions. They can only do what IAM Policies permit them to do. However, the policies vary by the amount of fine-grained control they allow.